# Geo Targeting with firebase In App messaging?

Tags: firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

is there a way to geo target my campaign in firebase In App Messaging ?
if I create a campaign for only my US users ? can I specific that in my console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app messaging can be targeted against:

[image: In-app-messaging targeting options]

User audiences in the above come from Google Analytics for Firebase. There you can define an audience on geographic location, so you can target the message to users in a specific geographic location that way.

When to display the (geo-targeted) message is determined in the app itself, by the occurrence of a specific Analytics event.